# firefox pick page action icon for dark / light themes

Tags: firefox, themes, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-quantum

I'm writing a web extension works on firefox. I want my icon works similar to the behavior of Firefox built in "Take a screenshot". The screenshot icon appeared in different colors when it shown in light theme / dark theme / in the menu.

I just added a `page_action` in manifest, and set an icon for it. The black icon looks ok on light theme, but become hard to use on dark theme. I want show light version of icon if browser is in dark theme (And also keep the icon in the menu black).

I had searched something about this, and find `browser_action` support `theme_icons` but `page_action` not.

What is the best practices to set different icons for different use case of page action icon?

[image]

What is the best prestic to config different icon color for different theme?

Answer (score 4):

After more google search, I found that this is implemented by screenshot add-on by adding `fill="context-fill" fill-opacity="context-fill-opacity"` on `<svg>` tag, and using svg for icon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="128px" height="128px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="context-fill" fill-opacity="context-fill-opacity">
  <path d="m0 0 H 16 V 16 H 0 Z"/>
</svg>
```

But unfortunately, this feature only enabled by default on mozilla-signed extensions. So this **won't work** on user defined extension.

Checkout bugzilla for more detail:

- [Bug 1377302 - Support fill="context-fill" for mozilla-signed WebExtension icons](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1377302)

Answer (score 3):

According to [Bug 1377302](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1377302), `context-fill` doesn't work because `svg.context-properties.content.enabled` is not enabled by default. The same pages says it was fixed in Firefox 55, but I'm using 60 and it is still not fixed.

So, right now, I would still use `context-fill` hoping that, in the near future, users will see the icon with the same color as the rest of the icons.